# How to fix the metaspace problem with jhipster?

Tags: java, jhipster

I have deployed my application jhipster on my server tomecat avyant to memoire 64 mb but the server does not launch the site and I recce these info in the file logs

```
2019-06-29 21:45:28.736  INFO 218336 --- [           main] ci.idc.islamelite.ApplicationWebXml      : The following profiles are active: dev,swagger
2019-06-29 21:45:38.954 DEBUG 218336 --- [           main] c.i.i.config.AsyncConfiguration          : Creating Async Task Executor
2019-06-29 21:45:42.758  WARN 218336 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-06-29 21:45:43.736 DEBUG 218336 --- [           main] c.i.i.config.CacheConfiguration          : Configuring Hazelcast
29-Jun-2019 21:45:43.908 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.instance.AddressPicker.null [LOCAL] [dev] [3.9.4] Picked [127.0.0.1]:5701, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5701], bind any local is true
29-Jun-2019 21:45:43.945 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Hazelcast 3.9.4 (20180420 - b8001d5) starting at [127.0.0.1]:5701
29-Jun-2019 21:45:43.945 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Copyright (c) 2008-2018, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
29-Jun-2019 21:45:43.945 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version: 1
29-Jun-2019 21:45:44.711 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Backpressure is disabled
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.487 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Starting 6 partition threads and 4 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.497 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.Diagnostics.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Diagnostics disabled. To enable add -Dhazelcast.diagnostics.enabled=true to the JVM arguments.
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.513 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTING
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.549 WARNING [main] com.hazelcast.instance.Node.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] No join method is enabled! Starting standalone.
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.550 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.system.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Cluster version set to 3.9
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.633 INFO [main] com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] [127.0.0.1]:5701 is STARTED
29-Jun-2019 21:45:47.634 INFO [hz.Islamelite.HealthMonitor] com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] processors=6, physical.memory.total=71.6G, physical.memory.free=2.2G, swap.space.total=0, swap.space.free=0, heap.memory.used=50.3M, heap.memory.free=10.2M, heap.memory.total=60.5M, heap.memory.max=60.5M, heap.memory.used/total=81.64%, heap.memory.used/max=81.64%, minor.gc.count=378, minor.gc.time=2347ms, major.gc.count=7, major.gc.time=1406ms, load.process=0.00%, load.system=40.13%, load.systemAverage=9.58, thread.count=45, thread.peakCount=45, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=0, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=1, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0
2019-06-29 21:45:47.702 DEBUG 218336 --- [           main] c.i.i.config.CacheConfiguration          : Starting HazelcastCacheManager
29-Jun-2019 21:46:22.677 INFO [hz.Islamelite.HealthMonitor] com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] processors=6, physical.memory.total=71.6G, physical.memory.free=2.0G, swap.space.total=0, swap.space.free=0, heap.memory.used=34.2M, heap.memory.free=29.3M, heap.memory.total=63.5M, heap.memory.max=63.5M, heap.memory.used/total=53.49%, heap.memory.used/max=53.49%, minor.gc.count=582, minor.gc.time=3930ms, major.gc.count=206, major.gc.time=31904ms, load.process=38.71%, load.system=70.59%, load.systemAverage=9.88, thread.count=55, thread.peakCount=55, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=1, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0
29-Jun-2019 21:47:39.511 WARNING [hz.Islamelite.cached.thread-13] com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.ClusterHeartbeatManager.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Resetting heartbeat timestamps because of huge system clock jump! Clock-Jump: 33811 ms, Heartbeat-Timeout: 60000 ms
29-Jun-2019 21:47:42.400 INFO [hz.Islamelite.HealthMonitor] com.hazelcast.internal.diagnostics.HealthMonitor.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] processors=6, physical.memory.total=71.6G, physical.memory.free=1.9G, swap.space.total=0, swap.space.free=0, heap.memory.used=34.6M, heap.memory.free=28.8M, heap.memory.total=63.5M, heap.memory.max=63.5M, heap.memory.used/total=53.50%, heap.memory.used/max=53.50%, minor.gc.count=1124, minor.gc.time=7525ms, major.gc.count=748, major.gc.time=108379ms, load.process=36.49%, load.system=78.96%, load.systemAverage=14.91, thread.count=58, thread.peakCount=59, cluster.timeDiff=0, event.q.size=0, executor.q.async.size=0, executor.q.client.size=0, executor.q.query.size=0, executor.q.scheduled.size=0, executor.q.io.size=0, executor.q.system.size=0, executor.q.operations.size=0, executor.q.priorityOperation.size=0, operations.completed.count=1, executor.q.mapLoad.size=0, executor.q.mapLoadAllKeys.size=0, executor.q.cluster.size=0, executor.q.response.size=0, operations.running.count=0, operations.pending.invocations.percentage=0.00%, operations.pending.invocations.count=0, proxy.count=0, clientEndpoint.count=0, connection.active.count=0, client.connection.count=0, connection.count=0
29-Jun-2019 21:48:09.627 SEVERE [hz.Islamelite.InvocationMonitorThread] com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationMonitor.null [127.0.0.1]:5701 [dev] [3.9.4] Metaspace
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Metaspace
```

Comment: Did you try increase Metaspace Size with **-XX:MetaspaceSize=size** jvm flag ?

Comment: Any reason why you deploy to Tomcat rather than using executable jar file ?

Comment: it is an online web hosting